# What might I be doing wrong to draw text with QPainter in QT 5 using C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

In my paintEvent method for a custom widget for a game I'm writing, After calling the various model objects' render() methods to render them to the widget, I am trying to render the "Hi-Score" text.  Here's the general code for just the text drawing:

```
painter.fillRect(event->rect(), QColor(0, 0, 0));
painter.drawImage(QRectF(event->rect().x(), event->rect().y() + 30, 512, 512), getGameBoardImage());

//...rendering other model components

painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 255)));
//painter.setFont(getGameFont());
painter.setFont(QFont("Times New Roman", 16, QFont::Bold));
painter.drawText(0, 0, "HI-SCORE");
```

I 'was' trying to draw the text in a custom font loaded from resource (I found an answer on here for that) but it wouldn't even display, even with a white brush.  I thought maybe it was because it was because I didn't 'set' a font, but setting it to Times New Roman doesn't display anything either.  What might I be doing wrong?  As you can see the background is a black background with the game board painted on top but leaving a small buffer at the top and bottom.  Do I need to do something special to display the text?  Please don't suggest using a QLabel because I am trying to keep it all in one widget if possible.  If I must, I will split the Hi-Score and 1-Ups into 2 other label sets with specialty fonts.

Answer (score 1):

you code look ok, but you are drawing at 0,0 which is the top left corner of the widget canvas AND the text is actually there but not visible...

draw instead at

```
painter.drawText(margin, y+margin, "HI-SCORE");
```

where y is the high of the font used to draw the text and margin is you know a little margin border to make it look better something like 5 units

update

you can get the value of the text you are painting doing somthing like

```
 QFont font("times", 25);
 QFontMetrics fm(font);
 int pixelsW{fm.width("HI-SCORE")};
 int pixelsH{fm.height()};
```

Comment: I did 0,0 because when I first started rendering components, I was rendering them at 0,0 (not setting any real coordinates).  It they all showed up at the top left of the widget.  So I just assumed doing drawText would do the same.  I started drawing my text at like 350, 25 but still nothing showed - I added the white brush, then the times new roman font and still nothing showed up so I changed it to 0, 0 b/c I have vision issues os maybe I was missing it in the middle of the board or something.  I'll try the suggestion but I also had started updating to use labels

Comment: I got the text to appear by setting a stylesheet.  But why won't setBrush work?  That's what I can't figure out.  I want to do something with making the text fade out in the one spot by setting the brush color to be a decreasing fraction of the total color.  I'm going to post another question though as it's slightly different and I doubt anyone will see this comment.